# Unable to activate free Google Cloud trial

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I constantly get directed to Try Google Platform for free, where I get prompted for country and acceptances. I accept, but then just get a spinning progress circle.

[image: Try Google Cloud for free]

I've noticed some errors in the Console log of the browser as well:

[image]

Would really love some pointers as to how to get past this step and get running

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually a browser issue. The [error 404](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes) means that the object, a request or an URI was not found.

1 - Try a different browser.

2 - Try it with the same browser but in incognito mode.

3 - It could be related to the proxy settings of the Internet connection, so try it in a different WiFi location.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have tried it in Edge, and also in incognito mode in Chrome, same result (the spinning circle). All other sites work, so I would be surprised if it's got something to do with the current Internet Connection, but I'll test that.

Comment: Try to clear the browser cache. I also suspect that it could be related to the SSL connectivity. If it still doesn't work, then you could open a new Issue in the [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) page. They will investigate it.

Comment: Thank you. I have found the correct place to report on Google, issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115421143

Answer (score 0):

I was able to activate the free trial by using a different internet connection, I will post more feedback from the Google defect report if/when I get it, as I still believe the user should be notified of the failure and not just wait with an expectation that the process will complete in some reasonable time.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The Internet connection could be using security policies (such as a proxy server) that would block access to some websites or some ports. It could have blocked access to the GCP trial registration [through a proxy server](http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/use-proxy-server.htm). This is just a suggestion, I do not know the specifications of your Internet connection so I can't confirm it.

Comment: Hopefully there will be good feedback from the HAR file submitted on the Google defect report.

Answer (score -1):

Tried in Firefox and it worked.
I had tried in Chrome, Incognito mode chrome and Safari, but failed in all. Finally worked in Firefox with same internet connection.